# A question on open sets

Tags: real-analysis

If we define **open** as: A set $O⊆R$ is open if for all points $a∈O$ there exists an
$\epsilon$-neighborhood $V_\epsilon(a)⊆O$.

Where $V_\epsilon(a) = \{x \in \mathbb{R}: | x - a | < \epsilon\}$
Now consider some open interval:

$(c,d) = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : c<x<d \}$

To see that $(c,d)$ is open, let $x \in (c,d)$ be arbitrary.

let $\epsilon = \text{min}\{x-c,d-x\}$, then it follows that $V_\epsilon(x) \subseteq (c,d)$

I am unable to see why this definition does not hold for a set containing one or more closed end points.

If my understanding is correct, let's take the closed interval $[1,10]$ and lets choose $x = 10$. So clearly $x \in  [1,10]$

$\epsilon = \text{min} \{10-1, 10-10\} = 0$

Then isn't it still true that
$V_\epsilon(x) \subseteq [1,10]$

Also, how would you express $V_\epsilon(x)$ in this instance, like it is expressed in the third line?

Comment: But your $\epsilon$-neighborhood is empty, when $\epsilon=0$, and thus it is not a neighborhood of the number 10.

Comment: @HowDoIMath
Are there any other reason as to why this doesn't hold for a set with one or both sides closed? Particularly, I don't see this problem arising when only one side is closed.

Additionally, how would you describe the set $V_\epsilon(x)$ in the last line?

Comment: I would describe it as in the beginning of your post. So $V_{\epsilon}(10) = \{x : |x-10|<\epsilon\}$. If $\epsilon=0$, then your condition is $|x-10|<0$, which is not possible, because the left hand side is non-negative. If you had considered instead the corresponding closed set, then your condition would be $|x-10|\leq 0$, which is only true for $x=10$. So the closed $\epsilon$-neighborhood for $\epsilon=0$ is just the set $\{0\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly focused on one of the end points.  For every point that is not an end point in the interval $[1,10]$, your argument for finding a ball around that point contained in $[1,10]$ works.

Now, if $x = 10$, we need to show that *every* ball around $10$ is *not* contained in $[1, 10]$.  Ok, so let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary.  $V_{\epsilon}(10) = (10 - \epsilon, 10 + \epsilon)$.  This clearly contains $10$ for each positive $\epsilon$.  BUT, is this interval contained in $[1,10]$?  Of course not.  The largest number in $[1,10]$ is $10$, but for each positive $\epsilon$, $(10 - \epsilon, 10 + \epsilon)$ contains a number bigger than $10$, and so this open set is *not* contained in $[1,10]$.

So, **for every** positive $\epsilon$, the ball around $10$ of radius $\epsilon$, which is equal to the interval $(10 - \epsilon, 10 + \epsilon)$, is **not** contained in $[1,10]$, which means $[1,10]$ is not open.

Instead of $x = 10$, you could have made a similar argument for $x = 1$.  I will leave it to you as an exercise to show that $x = 1$ causes the definition of open to fail for the set $[1,10]$.

Comment: Thanks, this was a great explanation!

Answer (score 2):

If you allowed $\epsilon$ to be $0$, then every set is open since the $0$-neighborhood of a point is just itself. For this reason, $\epsilon$ is understood to be positive.

Comment: Ah! I completely forgot that $\epsilon > 0$.
So what if we took the interval $[1,10)$

That way $\text{min} (x-1,10-x) $ would yield  a positive epsilon

Why would this set not be open?

Comment: @Championlancer Look at $x = 1$ in your new example of $[1,10)$.

Comment: Recall that an $\epsilon$-neighborhood subset must exist _at each_ $a \in O$. At $1$, you will not be able to find an $\epsilon$ neighborhood of $1$ which is a subset of $[1,10)$.

Comment: @user46944 my mistake - I am far too sleep deprived..

Thanks!

Comment: @Ken Your comment has helped a lot, I now believe I have a very good understanding of an open set.

Essentially, the boundary of a closed set, no such "ball" with an epsilon radius can exist that is entirely contained in the set.

Comment: Very good, then. :)